# Knockout custom binding handlers: $root is undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using a Knockout Custom Binding handler (borrowed from [Creating groups with Knockout.js foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591216/creating-groups-with-knockout-js-foreach)). Within the nested markup, I'd like to reference an observable that is located on the root of the view model. However the binding fails because $root is undefined. The same markup works fine with a standard foreach binding. I don't know why the custom hander prevents using $root.

Here is the source for the binding handler :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.foreachGrouped = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
     var groupedItems,
         options = valueAccessor();

    //create our own computed that transforms the flat array into rows/columns
    groupedItems = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            var index, length, group,
                result = [],
                count = +ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.count) || 1,
                items = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.data);

            //create an array of arrays (rows/columns)
            for (index = 0, length = items.length; index < length; index++) {
                if (index % count === 0) {
                   group = [];
                   result.push(group);
                }

                group.push(items[index]);
            }

            return result;
        },
        disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
    });  

    //use the normal foreach binding with our new computed
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { foreach: groupedItems });

    //make sure that the children of this element are not bound
    return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
}
};
```

Here is the html markup:

```
Header Text: <input data-bind="value: header" />
Group count: <input data-bind="value: count" />

<div data-bind="foreachGrouped: { data: items, count: count }">
   <h1 data-bind="html: $root.header"></h1>

   <ul data-bind="foreach: $data">
       <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the code used to wire up the view model:

```
ko.applyBindings({
  header: ko.observable("Group Header"),
      items: ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]),
      count: ko.observable(4)
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dk1do2vr/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the original bindingContext is lost in the handler.  So when `ko.applyBindingsToNode()` is called, it uses a completely new context (which is empty).  The handler predated when being able to specify what the binding context is, it was added in a later version of knockout.  You'll need to make adjustments to the handler to be able to preserve that context.

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { foreach: groupedItems }, bindingContext);
```

So the tweaks you need to make in the handler (removed irrelevant bits to be easier to see):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.foreachGrouped = {
    // need to get the binding context (fifth param)
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        //...

        //use the normal foreach binding with our new computed
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { foreach: groupedItems }, bindingContext); // pass in the binding context

        //...
    }
};
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dk1do2vr/4/)